# Make the <h3> less wide

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce the width of the `<h3>`

**HTML**

```css
 body {
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        header {
          background-color: #ff6600;
          color: #fff;
          padding: 20px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
          font-size: 28px;
          margin: 0;
        }

        main {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content-wrapper {
          background-color: #fff;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          padding: 20px;
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 1000px; /* Adjust this value to fit your screen */
          text-align: center;
          margin: 0 auto;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          max-height: 100%;
        }

        #story-number {
          padding: 10px 16px;
          font-size: 14px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 4px;
          width: 200px;
          height: 30px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #get-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
        }

        #get,
        #getRandom,
        #clear,
        #back { /* Style for the "Back" button */
          background-color: #ff6600;
          color: #fff;
          border: none;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          font-size: 16px;
          cursor: pointer;
          border-radius: 4px;
          transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          outline: none;
        }

        #get:hover,
        #getRandom:hover,
        #clear:hover,
        #back:hover { /* Hover effect */
          background-color: #ff9933; /* Change the background color on hover */
        }

        #story-container {
          background-color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          display: none;
          max-height: 320px; /* Set the maximum height here */
          overflow-y: auto; /* Add this line for the vertical scrollbar */
          padding: 0 20px; /* Add padding to the left and right */
        }

        #generated-text {
          font-size: 18px;
          line-height: 1.5;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          color: #333;
          text-align: center;
        }

        #generated-text span {
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #000;
          font-size: 20px;
        }

        #back { /* Style for the "Back" button */
          display: none;
          margin: 10px auto;
        }

        @media (min-width: 601px) {
          #content-wrapper {
            max-width: 600px;
          }
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
          #content-wrapper {
            max-width: 90%; /* Adjust width as needed */
            max-height: 80vh; /* Adjust height as needed */
            overflow-y: auto; /* Add vertical scrollbar */
          }
          #story-container {
            max-height: 58vh; /* Adjust the value as needed for your device */
          }
          #get,
          #getRandom,
          #clear,
          #back { /* Style for smaller screens */
            font-size: 10px !important;
            padding: 20px 20px !important;
          }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Stories - USA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/country.css">
</head>
<body data-country="usa">
    <header>
        <h1>Stories</h1>
        <h3>Argentina</h3>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="get-container">
          <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
          <button id="get" type="button">Get Story</button>
          <button id="getRandom" type="button">Random Story</button>
        </div>
        <div id="story-container">
          <!-- Story content will be displayed here -->
          <div id="generated-text"></div>
          <button id="back" type="button">Back</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="Scripts/argentina.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the `<h3>` to be less in width than the `<h1>` but I'm not sure how I would do that. I've been trying different ways but can't get it to look right. I thought I was done with the design but then realized that I wanted a smaller title which says what country's page I'm on. How can I make it work?

Comment: h3 {    display: inline-block;} is it what you're looking for?

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you don't want to give the entire left to right space for your h3 element. Please explain it well if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: I want it the same width as the container for the stories.

Comment: okay so you don't want to increase the font size of `Argentina` only wanted to streatch it out and match its width with "Stories" is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, just reduce the width and maybe even the height a little bit.

Comment: play with this rule adjust the unit value a little and you're sorted
`h3 {
    letter-spacing: .05rem;
}`

Comment: Hi Patrik. Two questions a day for the last six days may be an indication that you're not spending enough time on each thing. I understand that it is great to get help, but we're looking for high quality questions here that have been thoroughly researched and tried first.

Comment: Judging by the edits on this question and the comments on an answer, it seems that the solution was merged into this question. I have rolled that back, as otherwise it would invalidate the given answer. We want answers to remain valid, and for questions not to substantively change after a first answer is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the output in fullscreen.

Try this, just modified below CSS.

```
    *{
    margin:0;  // to reset default margin for all tags
    }
    header {
    background-color: #ff6600;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 600px;    // <-- added
    margin: 0 auto;      // <-- added
    }
    h3{
    margin:5px 0;   // like that you can adjust height
    }
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
}
body {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
h3{
 margin:5px 0;
 }
header {
background-color: #ff6600;
color: #fff;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
font-size: 28px;
margin: 0;
}
main {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
}
#content-wrapper {
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
padding: 20px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px; /* Adjust this value to fit your screen */
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
max-height: 100%;
}
#story-number {
padding: 10px 16px;
font-size: 14px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#get-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
#get,
#getRandom,
#clear,
#back { /* Style for the "Back" button */
background-color: #ff6600;
color: #fff;
border: none;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 4px;
transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
margin-bottom: 10px;
outline: none;
}
#get:hover,
#getRandom:hover,
#clear:hover,
#back:hover { /* Hover effect */
background-color: #ff9933; /* Change the background color on hover */
}
#story-container {
background-color: #fff;
text-align: center;
display: none;
max-height: 320px; /* Set the maximum height here */
overflow-y: auto; /* Add this line for the vertical scrollbar */
padding: 0 20px; /* Add padding to the left and right */
}
#generated-text {
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.5;
margin-bottom: 10px;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
}
#generated-text span {
font-weight: bold;
color: #000;
font-size: 20px;
}
#back { /* Style for the "Back" button */
display: none;
margin: 10px auto;
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
#content-wrapper {
max-width: 600px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
#content-wrapper {
max-width: 90%; /* Adjust width as needed */
max-height: 80vh; /* Adjust height as needed */
overflow-y: auto; /* Add vertical scrollbar */
}
#story-container {
max-height: 58vh; /* Adjust the value as needed for your device */
}
#get,
#getRandom,
#clear,
#back { /* Style for smaller screens */
font-size: 10px !important;
padding: 20px 20px !important;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Stories - USA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/country.css">
</head>
<body data-country="usa">
    <header>
        <h1>Stories</h1>
        <h3>Argentina</h3>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="get-container">
          <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
          <button id="get" type="button">Get Story</button>
          <button id="getRandom" type="button">Random Story</button>
        </div>
        <div id="story-container">
          <!-- Story content will be displayed here -->
          <div id="generated-text"></div>
          <button id="back" type="button">Back</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="Scripts/argentina.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I change the height of the <h3> ?

Comment: first add margin:0 in top 
like *{margin:0} why because by default h tag has margin at top and bottom.
check my code I rewrite the code for h3 height adjustment.

Comment: What do you mean with "in top" ?

Comment: check my code now @PatrikQvarnström

Comment: Looking at it now, it seems like it's the height of the header that needs to be changed.

Comment: Yes you are rite bro

Comment: I updated the CSS I posted earlier, so that's how I managed to fix it. Looks like I want it to now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255621/discussion-between-par-tha-and-patrik-qvarnstrom).

Answer (score 0):

try changing the max-width in CSS